# Appwrite puppeteer : no executable was found

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, appwrite

I managed to pass the chromium download with a modification of the environment variables, but when I run my function, I need to access the following binary (/usr/bin/chromium-browser). and I get an error telling me that: no executable was found.

Here is the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

module.exports = async function (req, res) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://apple.com');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
    await browser.close();
    res.send('Hello World!');
};
```

Is it possible to access files in this folder in an Appwrite function? If yes how?

Here is the complete error

```
Error: Tried to find the browser at the configured path (/usr/bin/chromium-browser), but no executable was found.
    at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/usr/code-start/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:98:23)
    at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/usr/code-start/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:166:25)
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (/usr/code-start/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:70:37)
    at async module.exports (/usr/code-start/src/index.js:5:21)
    at async /usr/local/src/server.js:68:13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppeteer requires an operating system dependency which isn't supported at the moment. You might want to  [this](https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite/issues/1037) issue to upvote the feature request.